# Select div class name with jquery

Tags: jquery, class, classname

I want to select second class value with jquery. For example;

```
<div class="mb-20"></div>
```

How can i get "20" value after from "mb-" ?

Comment: There is no "second" class value, that's a single className

Comment: If you want to target every element with a class that ends with `20`, you can do `$('[class$="20"]')`

Comment: You'd be parsing the "20" from the string "mb-20".  How you define your pattern for parsing the value is up to you.  You can split the string at the "-" and take the second index, or the last index.  You can replace "mb-" with nothing.  You can take the substring starting at index 3.  Etc.  What you have is a string.  What you want is part of that string.  Identify the pattern which gives you that part, and implement that.

Answer (score 1):

Here a sample of what you need, to illustrate i made this when you click the div.

```
// The selector just get all class starting with mb
$('[class^="mb"]').on('click', function() {
   alert($(this).attr('class').split('-')[1]);
});
```

And here is the [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/hfezwfqj/)

Comment: Thanks so much for your help.

There is just a problem, when you add a more class, it taking it too;

https://jsfiddle.net/hfezwfqj/1/

Answer (score 0):

If you have already selected the div you can iterate over its classes, and split each class on hyphen.  Something like...

```
$.each($('div').attr('class').split(/s+/), function(idx, val) {
    var parts = val.split('-');
    var classBase = parts[0];
    var classModifier = parts.length > 1 ? parts[1] : null;

    if(classModifier !== null) alert("found class modifier" + classModifier);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If `div`s have more than one class, you can do this:

```
$('[class^="mb"]').on('click', function() {
     alert($(this).attr('class').split(' ')[0].split('-')[1]);
});
```

This will get **first class of element first**, second, split it with `-` and return the number.

[Here is the updated Gonzalo Bahamondez's fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/hfezwfqj/2/)